# Реализация Undo/Redo для свойств ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть класс `PersonVm`, который представляет информацию о человеке:

```
public class PersonVm : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
      get {return _name; }
      set 
      {   
          _name = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged();
      }
    }
}
```

Класс `PersonManager` представляет собой коллекцию персон и позволяет добавлять/удалять персоны, а также откатывать эти изменения через `UndoRedoService`:

```
public class PersonManager  : BaseViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons {get;set;}
    public UndoRedoService UndoRedoService {get;set;} = new UndoRedoService();
}
```

Хотелось бы также откатывать изменения, которые происходят в `PersonVm`. 
Можно было бы подписаться на событие `PropertyChanged`у всех персон и получать название свойства в котором произошло изменение, текущее и новое значения.

Но в таком случае откатывать изменения пришлось бы через рефлексию — искать по названию нужное свойство и менять его. А это не слишком быстрый способ.

Возможно сделать как-то иначе?

Comment: Через рефлексию не обязательно, можно и вручную через `switch-case`. Другой вариант - клонировать целиком экземпляр и хранить его, но там тоже свои минусы

Comment: @Андрей, Через `switch-case` можно конечно, но хотелось бы что-то универсальнее. Свойств в `PersonVm` много, плюс наследников у `PersonVm` будет большое количество и вручную заполнять все свойства не хочется. Весь экземпляр хранить вариант, но не слишком ли это забьет память?

Comment: Если объект сложный, то его глубокое клонирование тоже придется писать вручную. Ну и объемов я ваших не знаю. Нужно выбрать что вам важнее скорость или потребляемая память? Вам здесь действительно скорость важна? Я так понимаю, что команды Undo/Redo вызывает пользователь, поэтому рефлексия одного свойства - мелочь в сравнении, например, с нагрузками от отображения этого всего в GUI.

Comment: По клонированию здесь полезная информация со ссылкой на сравнение способов: https://stackoverflow.com/a/966534/6766879

Comment: @maxwell Если вы хотите универсального решения, которому можно было бы передавать любой объект, а он запоминал его состояние и мог вернуть, то вам придется использовать клонирование с помощью рефлексии, другого способа для .Net я не представляю. Но, как мне представляется, все не так уж и плохо. Рефлексия вряд ли заметно замедлит выполнение, а что касается памяти, то историю хранения операций можно сделать ограниченного размера (к примеру 10 действий), этим вы избежите чрезмерного использования памяти.

Comment: @maxwell Кроме того, можно не использовать клонирование объекта, а создать отдельный тип для хранения изменений. class Chnage{ Object linkToChangedObject; PropertyInfo changedProperty; object Value }. Таким образом, вы сможете еще сэкономить память, поскольку вам не надо будет желать копию всего объекта после изменения  одного его свойства.

Comment: @Maxwell вам обязательно нужно реализовывать `Undo/Redo` самостоятельно. Почему не использовать готовые решения?

Comment: @sp7, Нет, не обязательно. Можете подсказать какие именно решения есть? Я нашел лишь реализации `UndoStack'a` в который нужно предоставлять `Undo/Redo` методы.

Comment: @Maxwell постараюсь чуть позже привести пример решения, которое работает из  коробки.

Comment: @sp7, Было бы отлично.

Comment: @maxwell, ну а вы пробовали решение с рефлексией и оно вам не подошло или не пробовали еще? У меня в принципе вышло всего строк 70. Могу оформить в виде ответа

Comment: @Андрей, Еще не пробовал.

Comment: Если вы будете пользоваться готовыми фреймворками, они тоже скорее всего используют под капотом рефлексию. И, думаю, будет ещё медленнее.

Comment: @Андрей, Покажите ваше решение.

Comment: @maxwell, теперь только завтра, решение осталось на работе, а я уехал домой. Залить на Github не догадался.

Comment: @Андрей, Хорошо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я расширил базовый класс для `ViewModel`, чтобы он вёл историю изменений.
У меня пример тестовый, поэтому так, вам скорее всего потребуются оба класса - с ведением истории и без нее, чтобы можно было наследоваться либо от того либо от другого.
А еще лучше завести список с перечнем классов и их свойств по которым должна вестись история изменений, а может даже и сочинить вместо этого кастомный атрибут.

У меня был такой класс:

```
abstract class Vm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Я его дополнил следующим функционалом:

```
    // Пришлось добавить флаги для того чтобы отличать обычную
    //  установку свойства от Undo/Redo
    static bool isUndoProcess = false;
    static bool isRedoProcess = false;

    // Пара стеков для хранения истории
    static Stack<(object Obj, string Prop, object OldValue)> undoHistory
        = new Stack<(object Obj, string Prop, object OldValue)>();

    static Stack<(object Obj, string Prop, object OldValue)> redoHistory
        = new Stack<(object Obj, string Prop, object OldValue)>();

    static void Undo()
    {
        if (undoHistory.Count == 0) return;
        var undo = undoHistory.Pop();
        UndoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        // Обернуто для того чтобы в случае исключения флаг всё равно снимался
        try
        {
            isUndoProcess = true;
            undo.Obj.GetType().GetProperty(undo.Prop).SetValue(undo.Obj, undo.OldValue);
        }
        finally
        {
            isUndoProcess = false;
        }
    }

    static void Redo()
    {
        if (redoHistory.Count == 0) return;
        var redo = redoHistory.Pop();
        RedoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        try
        {
            isRedoProcess = true;
            redo.Obj.GetType().GetProperty(redo.Prop).SetValue(redo.Obj, redo.OldValue);
        }
        finally
        {
            isRedoProcess = false;
        }
    }

    static void SaveHistory(object obj, string propertyName, object value)
    {
        if (isUndoProcess)
        {
            redoHistory.Push((obj, propertyName, value));
            RedoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        else if (isRedoProcess)
        {
            undoHistory.Push((obj, propertyName, value));
            UndoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            undoHistory.Push((obj, propertyName, value));
            UndoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            redoHistory.Clear();
            RedoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    static void ClearHistory()
    {
        undoHistory.Clear();
        UndoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        redoHistory.Clear();
        RedoCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    // Команды, которые можно выставлять в GUI
    public static DelegateCommand UndoCommand { get; }
        = new DelegateCommand(_ => Undo(), _ => undoHistory.Count > 0);
    public static DelegateCommand RedoCommand { get; }
        = new DelegateCommand(_ => Redo(), _ => redoHistory.Count > 0);
    public static DelegateCommand ClearHistoryCommand { get; }
        = new DelegateCommand(_ => ClearHistory());
```

Теперь добавим сохранение в метод `Set<T>`:

```
    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            return false;
        // Сюда
        SaveHistory(this, propertyName, field);
        field = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
```

Обратите внимание, решение не безопасно к потокам, но это и не требуется, т.к. вы должны обновлять свойства VM только в потоке GUI

Здесь использована следующая реализация команды:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    protected readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    protected readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, _ => true) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(canExecute));
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        => CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Ну и пример использования:

```
class PeopleVm : Vm
{
    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    string lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get => firstName;
        set => Set(ref firstName, value);
    }

    public string SecondName
    {
        get => secondName;
        set => Set(ref secondName, value);
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get => lastName;
        set => Set(ref lastName, value);
    }
}

class MainVm : Vm
{
    public ObservableCollection<PeopleVm> Peoples { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<PeopleVm>();

    public DelegateCommand AddPeopleCommand { get; }

    public MainVm()
    {
        Peoples.Add(new PeopleVm { FirstName = "Иван", SecondName = "Петрович", LastName = "Сидоров" });
        AddPeopleCommand = new DelegateCommand(_ => Peoples.Add(new PeopleVm()));
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ToolBar>
        <Button Content="Undo" Command="{Binding UndoCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Redo" Command="{Binding RedoCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearHistoryCommand}"/>
        <Separator/>
        <Button Content="Add" Command="{Binding AddPeopleCommand}"/>
    </ToolBar>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Peoples}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="DarkGreen"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Margin="2" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3,3,0,3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                                </Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,3,3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Имя:"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Отчество:"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Text="{Binding SecondName}"/>

                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Фамилия:"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                                     Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

[image: Undo-Redo test]

---

Добавляем атрибут!

Создайте класс атрибута:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class UndoRedoAttribute : Attribute { }
```

В начало метода `Vm.SaveHistory` добавим проверку наличия атрибута:

```
        if (obj.GetType()
               .GetProperty(propertyName)
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UndoRedoAttribute), true)
               .Length == 0) return;
```

Всё! Теперь достаточно к нужным свойствам прицепить этот атрибут:

```
class PeopleVm : Vm
{
    ...

    [UndoRedo]
    public string FirstName
    { ... }

    public string SecondName
    { ... }

    [UndoRedo]
    public string LastName
    { ... }
}
```

И, вуаля, история ведется только по указанным свойствам!

Comment: Добавил в ответ использование атрибута

Comment: Спасибо! Скажите, а как вы поступаете с методом `Set<T>` когда в `VM` свойства лишь обертка над свойствами модели? Т.е. `Name {get => Model.Name}`. Ведь через `ref` нельзя передать свойство.

Comment: @maxwell, ну можно попробовать что-то типа такого:
`set
{
 var temp = Model.Name;
 if (Set(ref temp, value))
     Model.Name = temp;
}`

Comment: Тогда `NotifyPropertyChanged` придется выносить в блок `if`, чтобы событие срабатывало после присваивания значения.

Comment: Хм, да. Выглядит кривовато. Вообще обычная практика - не работать напрямую с модельными объектами, а иметь их VM-аналоги. А конвертировать их туда-сюда непосредственно при необходимости. Например загрузили из базы, смаппили на объекты VM, пользователь их отредактировал, жмет Сохранить и они маппятся на View-объекты и сохраняются. При таком подходе, например, кнопка отмены вообще почти не имеет кода, мы просто не сохраняем ничего.

Comment: @Андрей: А хорошо вышло, кстати.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, я сам рад! Особенно использованию атрибута, т. к. раньше не было повода их испробовать.

Answer (score 3):

Так как реализация "**отката**" изменений самостоятельно дело довольное утомительное. Проще использовать готовое решение. Одним из WPF-Фреймворков, который предоставляет данную функциональность из коробки является [Catel](http://catelproject.com/).

Ниже показан простейший пример такого приложения:

1) Создаем новый проект: `File - New - Project... - WpfApplication`.

2) Устанавливаем **Catel**.

```
PM> Install-Package Catel.MVVM
PM> Install-Package Catel.Core -Version 4.5.4
```

3) В проекте создаем стандартную  структуру из папок: **Models**, **ViewModels**, **Views**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4) В папке **Models** cоздаем класс **User**, представляющий нашу модель, он будет содержать всего пару свойств **Name** и **LastName** и наследуем его от **ModelBase**.

```
public class UserModel : ModelBase
{
     public string Name
     {
         get { return GetValue<string>(AuthorProperty); }
         set { SetValue(AuthorProperty, value); }
     }

     public static readonly PropertyData AuthorProperty = 
        RegisterProperty(nameof(Name), typeof(string), string.Empty);

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(LastNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData LastNameProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(LastName), typeof(string), string.Empty);
}
```

5) Далее в папке **Views** создаем нашу **View**, назовем ее **MainView**, ее разметка представлена ниже. Обратите внимание, что тип окна `catel:Window`.

```
<catel:Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.MainView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
              Title="MainWindow"
              Width="525"
              Height="350"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
              mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Header="Имя" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding LastName}"
                                    Header="Фамилия" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Command="{Binding EditUserCommand}"
                Content="Редактировать" />
    </Grid>
</catel:Window>
```

6) В папке **ViewModels** создаем **ViewModel** для нашей **MainView**. Назовем ее **MainViewModel**.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    // Сервис открытия окон. Поставляется из коробки.
    private readonly IUIVisualizerService _uiVisualizerService;

    public MainViewModel(IUIVisualizerService uiVisualizerService)
    {
        _uiVisualizerService = uiVisualizerService;

        EditUserCommand = new Command(EditUserAsync, () => SelectedUser != null);
    }

    private async void EditUserAsync()
    {
        // Создаем нашу ViewModel.
        var editUserViewModel = new EditUserViewModel(SelectedUser);

        // Передаем объект ViewModel сервису окон, он самостоятельно найдет соответствующую ей View.
        await _uiVisualizerService.ShowDialogAsync(editUserViewModel);
    }

    // Инициализируем коллекцию тестовыми данными.
    protected override Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        Users.Add(new UserModel()
        {
            Name = "Вася",
            LastName = "Иванов"
        });
        Users.Add(new UserModel()
        {
            Name = "Петя",
            LastName = "Петров"
        });

        return base.InitializeAsync();
    }

    public Command EditUserCommand { get; }

    // Catel использует DP для уведомления View об изменении.

    // Выбранный в DataGrid пользователь. 
    public UserModel SelectedUser
    {
        get { return GetValue<UserModel>(SelectedUserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedUserProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedUserProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(SelectedUser),
            typeof(UserModel));

    // Список всех пользователей.
    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<UserModel>>(UsersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UsersProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData UsersProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(Users), 
            typeof(ObservableCollection<UserModel>), 
            new ObservableCollection<UserModel>());
}
```

7) Создаем представление, для редактирования нашего пользователя, оно будет следующим. Обратите внимание, что тип окна `catel:DataWindow`.

```
<catel:DataWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.Views.EditUserView"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModels"
              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:EditUserViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
              mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Text="Имя" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Text="Фамилия" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

8) И ViewModel для него:

```
public class EditUserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EditUserViewModel(UserModel user)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    // Свойства, которые связаны со View и отражаются на объект редактируемой модели. 
    [ViewModelToModel(nameof(User), nameof(UserModel.Name))]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(AuthorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AuthorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData AuthorProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(Name), typeof(string), string.Empty);

    // Свойства, которые связаны со View и отражаются на объект редактируемой модели. 
    [ViewModelToModel(nameof(User), nameof(UserModel.LastName))]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(LastNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData LastNameProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(LastName), typeof(string), string.Empty);

    // Переданный объект модели, который мы редактируем.
    [Model]
    public UserModel User
    {
        get { return GetValue<UserModel>(UserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly PropertyData UserProperty =
        RegisterProperty(nameof(User), typeof(UserModel));
}
```

9) В принципе на этом все, в **Solution Explorer** наш проект теперь выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

10) Теперь если запустить приложение, выбрать в DataGrid какого-нибудь пользователя и начать редактировать его, а после нажать на кнопку  **Отмена** все изменения будут отменены.

---

P.S. Что делать, если не охота использовать этот громоздкий синтаксис с использованием **DP** из **Catel**?

**Вариант 1**

Установить Catel.Fody

```
PM> Install-Package Catel.Fody -Version 2.17.0
```

В этом случае нужный код для **DP** будет сгенерирован автоматически, путем перезаписи **IL**, после чего во **ViewModel** достаточно написать так:

```
public class EditUserViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public EditUserViewModel(UserModel user)
    {
        User = user;
    }

    [ViewModelToModel(nameof(User), nameof(UserModel.Name))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ViewModelToModel(nameof(User), nameof(UserModel.LastName))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Model]
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
}
```

**Вариант 2**

Использовать [Code Snippets](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/622641)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. В вашем варианте мы можем откатить изменения только одного пользователя. А можно ли реализовать `Undo/Redo' когда мы подряд редактируем несколько пользователей и только затем откатываем изменения?

Comment: @Maxwell, т.е. вы имеете ввиду ситуацию, когда я скопом отредактировал, предположим, 10 пользователей, потом нажал "Отмена" и все изменения, которые я произвел с этими 10 пользователями откатились в состояние, которое было до редактирования?

Comment: Нет, обычная история изменений. Вы редактируете пользователей, затем нажимаете Ctrl+z и последний отредактированный пользователь возвращает свои первоначальные значения. Нажимаете еще раз и предпоследний пользователь возвращает первоначальные значения.

Comment: @Maxwell на самом деле, когда вы нажимаете на кнопку "Отмена"  Catel для текущей VM вызывает метод `CancelViewModelAsync` и `CloseViewModelAsync`, что приводит к отмене изменений и закрытию диалогового окна. Следовательно, вам никто не мешает написать логику, в которой вы для нужной VM самостоятельно вызовете метод `CancelViewModelAsync`.

Comment: А как быть с `Redo`?

Comment: @Maxwell что бы использовать Undo/Redo в связке нужно использовать сервис `IMementoService` он так же идет в комплекте.